# Banner image blurry and grainy on Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I would like to place a image background on the homepage with the exact size of 1920x1080 px. But it loads a 960x540 version and therefore blurry and grainy.
Umbraco version 12.1.2

Any photo I upload, set the width to 1500px, but I would like it to 1920px

Comment: Does it support CSS code?  Style='width:1920px;' would do the trick.

Comment: Oh nice, okay I checked and it seems it does support CSS.  If you can find the element in question, just add the inline code I posted above.  If it works, let me know and I will type up an official answer.

Comment: I don't think it's a question of CSS, when I upload a 1920px photo, the system resizes it to 1500px and then displays it at 100%, thus doing a stretch

Comment: When it has the image, if you inpect it in the browser, and redownload it manually, is it the orignal full sized image just showing at 1500 or its actually converting during the upload process to be that size?  Now check the dimensions.  If the software is doing it, there must be an optoin somewhere in there to set the limit, but in normal situations, a website system would resize the image using CSS such as I mentioned above.  The downside is its a slower download, the upside is it is a higher resolution.

Comment: Yes, it is resized when uploading. For this reason I was asking where I can change this option on umbraco

Comment: Most likely in the Razor template (CSHTML file) it's using a "GetCropUrl" method where it tells Umbraco to resize the image to 1500 px width

Comment: yes I know... I'm asking how to increase to 1920px

Comment: can you find a place in code where the image is rendering?